# Jquery .delay (or setTimeout) issue

Tags: jquery, delay

I am writing a little function for pop-up window, and I am stuck in to a problem with delay (or setTimeout). What's the idea behind function: you can tell which block need to be toggled, and after which time it will disappear from the view. If delayed set to 0, then it's not applied, it will not disappear. Here is the code:

```
function toggleModal(et, delayed) {
       //detect whether popup is visible or not 
       if(et.hasClass('acc-edit-fn'))
       {
            //hidden - then display
            //when IE - fade immediately
            if($.browser.msie)
                {
                 $('#opacity-modal').height($(document).height()).toggleClass('acc-edit-fn');
                }
            else
            //in all the rest browsers - fade slowly
                {
                 $('#opacity-modal').height($(document).height()).toggleClass('acc-edit-fn').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
                }

            et.html($(this).html()).toggleClass('acc-edit-fn');
            if(delayed > 0) {       
                setTimeout(et.toggleClass('acc-edit-fn'), delayed);
                setTimeout(('#opacity-modal').toggleClass('acc-edit-fn').removeAttr('style'), delayed);         
            }
       }
       else
       {
        //visible - then hide   
        $('#opacity-modal').toggleClass('acc-edit-fn').removeAttr('style');
        et.toggleClass('acc-edit-fn');  
       }
      };
```

This is the part where everything crashes:

```
if(delayed > 0) {       
    setTimeout(et.toggleClass('acc-edit-fn'), delayed);
    setTimeout(('#opacity-modal').toggleClass('acc-edit-fn').removeAttr('style'), delayed);         
}
```

It's doesn't matter what I will use for delay - setTimeout or delay(), nothing is working. What is the possible way to wait for "delayed" and fire events only after that?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22u8Y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeouthttps://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) accepts a function or code snippet (string format) to execute after delay. Also you missed `$` before `('#opacity-modal')`

Use

```
if(delayed > 0) {       
    setTimeout(function(){et.toggleClass('acc-edit-fn'); }, delayed);
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#opacity-modal').toggleClass('acc-edit-fn').removeAttr('style');}, delayed);          
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working! I will accept your answer after timer.